# publish file to image topic

Tags: ros, image, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to publish an image file (i.e. image1.jpg) to an image topic I can display in rviz (/camera/image).  Can anyone tell me a simple way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99831/publish-file-to-image-topic/) by [Brad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2761/brad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-02-11**:
Did you ever get an example working that you care to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use opencv imread on the file and then rosbridge to convert to the sensor_msgs/Image format: http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/40209/mohammad/) on 2021-03-08**:
Thanks for the answer. How to publish images in a folder continuously?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-05-19**:
Try out https://github.com/lucasw/image_manip/blob/master/image_manip/scripts/image_folder_publisher.py

```
rosrun image_manip image_folder_publisher.py _folder:=`pwd`
```

and there are likely more to be found elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what I got working in Hydro

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

    cv_bridge::CvImage cv_image;
    cv_image.image = cv::imread("/home/taylor/Pictures/face.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv_image.encoding = "bgr8";
    sensor_msgs::Image ros_image;
    cv_image.toImageMsg(ros_image);

  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("/static_image", 1);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(5);

  while (nh.ok()) 
  {
    pub.publish(ros_image);
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) with karma: 385 on 2014-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/40209/mohammad/) on 2021-03-08**:
Thanks for the answer. How to publish images in a folder continuously?

**Comment by [NecessaryThat](https://answers.ros.org/users/72380/necessarythat/) on 2021-03-26**:
@mohammad did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a node for this:

```
rosrun image_publisher image_publisher /absolute/path.png
```

---

Originally posted by [Beshari](https://answers.ros.org/users/38636/beshari/) with karma: 51 on 2022-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3